# Python dictionary.keys() error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.2

I am trying to use the `.keys()` and instead of getting a list of the keys like 
always have in the past. However I get this.

```
b = { 'video':0, 'music':23 }
k = b.keys()
print( k[0] )

>>>TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

print( k )
dict_keys(['music', 'video'])
```

it should just print ['music', 'video'] unless I'm going crazy.

What's going on?

Comment: Since nobody linked the official documentation yet, I'll do it: [**Dictionary view object**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

Comment: Please note that dictionaries are unordered, so that b.keys()[0] is generally not a very useful thing to do.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Python 3 changed the behavior of `dict.keys` such that it now returns a `dict_keys` object, which is iterable but not indexable (it's like the old `dict.iterkeys`, which is gone now). You can get the Python 2 result back with an explicit call to `list`:

```
>>> b = { 'video':0, 'music':23 }
>>> k = list(b.keys())
>>> k
['music', 'video']
```

or just

```
>>> list(b)
['music', 'video']
```

Comment: just `list(b)` does the same

Comment: I see thank you. So how would you go about iterating through the dict_keys?

Comment: @tokageKitayama: `for x in b.keys()` or just `for x in b`.

Comment: Unless you're using the `set`-like behaviors of the keys view, just don't use `.keys()`. The dict itself supports iteration and contains checks of its keys with no calls; it's wasteful and unnecessarily verbose to actually call `.keys()` when you're no using it for something different from what the original `dict` does.

Answer (score 8):

If you assigned `k` like so:

```
k = list(b.keys())
```

your code will work.

As the error says, the `dict_keys` type does not support indexing.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the breaking changes between Python 2 and 3.

In Python 2:

```
>>> help(dict.keys)
keys(...)
    D.keys() -> list of D's keys
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> help(dict.keys)
keys(...)
    D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys
```

This change in behavior makes a lot of sense since a dict is semantically unordered and its keys are unique - just like a set.

This change means that you don't have to create a new list of keys every time you want to do some kind of set comparison with a dict's keys.

## Getting the same behavior in 2 and 3

To help transition to Python 3, Python 2.7 has another dict method, `viewkeys`. The `viewkeys` method is most similar to Python 3's `dict.keys` method:

```
>>> d
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None, 'd': None}
>>> for k in d.viewkeys(): print k
... 
a
c
b
d
>>> d.viewkeys() & set('abc')
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

In Python 3, the closest analog to the old behavior is to pass `dict.keys()` to `list`:

```
>>> d
{'d': None, 'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None}
>>> list(d.keys())
['d', 'a', 'c', 'b']
```

Or just pass the dict to `list`, since a dict will iterate over its keys anyways:

```
>>> list(d)
['d', 'a', 'c', 'b']
```

You could create a utility functions to abstract the behavior over 2 and 3:

```
if hasattr(dict, 'viewkeys'): # Python 2.7
    def keys(d):
        return d.viewkeys()
else:  # Python 3
    def keys(d):
        return d.keys()
```

And pass a dict to `list` to get the list form, and in both 2 and 3, you'll get the same output:

```
>>> d
{'b': None, 'a': None, 'c': None, 'd': None}
>>> keys(d)
dict_keys(['b', 'a', 'c', 'd'])
>>> list(d)
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a list of keys from a dictionary you can directly do like this:

```
b = {"name": "xyz", "class":"abc", "college": "qwert"}  
key_list = list(b)
```

key_list will contain all the key names as a list, though, this will not repeats a key, if found more than once. Duplicate keys will be counted as one.

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
b = { 'video':0, 'music':23,"picture":12 }
random.choice(tuple(b.items()))

# Returns a random dictionary entry as a tuple:
# ('music', 23)
```

Comment: You should write more details regarding the answer (entering text answer and explanation, why is something working that way) + use better formating for the code directly (to keep standarts for the SO).