# Python - Printing String of Key in a Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is the following,

```
prices = {'banana':'4', 'apple':'2', 'orange':'1.5', 'pear':'3'}
stock = {'banana':6, 'apple':0, 'orange':32, 'pear':15}

print(prices.keys)
print("price :" + str(prices.values))
print("stock :" + str(stock.values))
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a spit out that looks as if I asked for the type. What gives?

Actually, my code logic is wrong.

I want the code to spit out the following

key
price : values
stock : values

For Example, this is how it should look

apple
price: 2
stock: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
prices = {'banana':'4', 'apple':'2', 'pear':'3'}
stock = {'banana':6, 'orange':32, 'pear':15}
for item in (prices.keys() & stock.keys()):
    print (item,"price:",prices.get(item,'-'),"stock:",stock.get(item,0))
```

Produces

```
orange price: - stock: 32
pear price: 3 stock: 15
banana price: 4 stock: 6
apple price: 2 stock: 0
```

Using get with a default will help if the stock and prices dictionaries contain different friuts ('keys') in each. The `.get()` function really helps here.

As mentioned by mgilson the following line is where the full set of fruit is created.

```
prices.keys() & stock.keys()  #{'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple'}
```

I've also done this using set before

```
set(prices.keys().extend(stock.keys())
```

But I prefer the `&` approach.

Comment: Why does the orange price not come up but the apple does?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I just used | instead of & and got my desired result. Thank you again!

Answer (score 8):

You need to call the methods to get anything useful:

```
print (prices.keys())
```

However, in python3.x, this still isn't particularly nice for printing since it'll print extra junk that you probably don't want to see.

You might want to consider using `str.join` on the object returned from `dict.keys()` or `dict.values()`:

```
print (' '.join(prices.keys()))
```

`str.join` does pretty much what you'd expect it to.  The string on the left is the delimiter that gets inserted between each element in the iterable you pass to `join`.  For example:

```
"!".join(["foo","bar","baz"])
```

will result in the string:  `"foo!bar!baz"`.  The only gotcha here is that each element in the iterable that you pass to `str.join` must be a string.

---

As for your edit,

```
prices = {'banana':'4', 'apple':'2', 'orange':'1.5', 'pear':'3'}
stock = {'banana':6, 'apple':0, 'orange':32, 'pear':15}
prices.keys() & stock.keys()  #{'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple'}
for item in (prices.keys() & stock.keys()):
    print (item,"price:",prices[item],"stock:",stock[item])
```

which outputs:

```
orange price: 1.5 stock: 32
pear price: 3 stock: 15
banana price: 4 stock: 6
apple price: 2 stock: 0
```

seems like it is what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with     join. I'll look it up now.

Comment: thank you but even with the fix, the code is not doing what I thought it would. Could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @algebr -- I saw you edit.  I'm not sure that I understand what you expect the output to be.  Could you clarify the post showing exactly what you want the output to be?

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much again. but line 3 of your code, what does it do? it just seems like its floating..?

Comment: @algebr -- It is floating.  I put it there to demonstrate what `dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()` does.  In this case, it really does pretty much the same thing as `dict1.keys()` since your dictionarys have the same keys -- If they didn't, it would return the intersection of the two sets of keys.

Comment: or just `print(' '.join(prices))` instead of calling `.keys()`

Comment: @gnibbler -- Very true.  I wrote that back when I was assuming OP wanted to do the values as well.

Comment: As alluded to in this answer, `dict.keys()` returns an object of type `dict_keys`, not an index-able object like a list of strings. To get a list of the keys as strings, you should simply use `list(dict)`.

Answer (score 1):

The top two answers recommend using `.keys()`, but [note that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953627/python-dictionary-keys-error) this returns an object of type `dict_keys`, not an index-able object like a list of strings. To get a list of the keys as strings, you should simply cast the dictionary as a list: `list(my_dict)`.

```
>>> prices = {'banana':'4', 'apple':'2', 'pear':'3'}
>>> print(prices.keys())
dict_keys(['banana', 'apple', 'pear'])
>>> prices.keys()[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
>>> print(list(prices))
['banana', 'apple', 'pear']
>>> list(prices)[2]
'pear'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both dictionaries/objects have the same keys you can use a simple for loop to iterate over one of the dictionaries and print the price and stock of each item.

```
prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3}
stock  = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
for key in prices:
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
    print "prices: %s" % prices[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3}
stock  = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
for key in prices:
    print key
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
    print "prices: %s" % prices[key]
```

which outputs:

```
orange
stock: 32
prices: 1.5
pear
stock: 15
prices: 3
banana
stock: 6
prices: 4
apple
stock: 0
prices: 2
=> None
```